# What is the default client header in Python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, header, python-requests, http-headers

What is the default client header string in python requests module? I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.x

Note that I use Session() object as follows:

```
se = requests.Session()
se.mount("https://",mytlsAdapter())
```

and `mytlsAdapter()` is used to configure some TLS configurations similar to the description [here](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version), but not touched anything related to the client headers.

I did not specify any client header string. But I need to know what is the default one if I do not specify one. How to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response object includes the request object that generated it.

So, you can see what headers were sent:

```
response = requests.get(...)
print response.request.headers
```